# Play Framework 2.4.1: How to get configuration values just after configuration file has been loaded

Tags: scala, playframework

I need to read some configuration values just after the configuration file has been loaded but before the application actually starts.

In Play 2.3.x I used to override `GlobalSettings.onLoadConfig`, which is deprecated in Play 2.4.x. The official documentation says one should use `GuiceApplicationBuilder.loadConfig` instead.

Again, the documentation is a bit poor and I was unable to find more details or an example... so any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1. Before app starts

If you need to read configuration before app starts, this approach can be used:

`modules/CustomApplicationLoader.scala`:

```
package modules

import play.api.ApplicationLoader
import play.api.Configuration
import play.api.inject._
import play.api.inject.guice._

class CustomApplicationLoader extends GuiceApplicationLoader() {
  override def builder(context: ApplicationLoader.Context): GuiceApplicationBuilder = {
    println(context.initialConfiguration) // <- the configuration
    initialBuilder
      .in(context.environment)
      .loadConfig(context.initialConfiguration)
      .overrides(overrides(context): _*)
  }
}
```

`conf/application.conf` has the following added:

```
play.application.loader = "modules.CustomApplicationLoader"
```

With that, I see the following in console (snipped as too long):

```
Configuration(Config(SimpleConfigObject({"akka":{"actor":{"creation-timeout":"20s"...
```

Source: [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Advanced:-Extending-the-GuiceApplicationLoader).

### 2. Not before app starts

If you don't need to read configuration before app starts, this approach can be used instead: (it's so embarrassingly simple) the `Module` bindings method takes a Play Environment and Configuration for you to read:

```
class HelloModule extends Module {
  def bindings(environment: Environment,
               configuration: Configuration) = {
    println(configuration) // <- the configuration
    Seq(
      bind[Hello].qualifiedWith("en").to[EnglishHello],
      bind[Hello].qualifiedWith("de").to[GermanHello]
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: In case it helps, it seems you can inject more (like Configuration) into the Impl that gets created simply by adding to the constructor as such:

`@Singleton
class CustomTaskImpl implements CustomTask {
    @Inject
    public CustomTaskImpl(ApplicationLifecycle lifecycle, Configuration configuration) {
        // onstart

        lifecycle.addStopHook( () -> {
            // onstop
            return F.Promise.pure(null);
        });
    }
}`